# How to troubleshoot vulkan blank screen?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I just went through the LunarG 'drawcube' samples and incorporated the code into my engine.  When I run, I get a black screen, since black is the clear color.  I can change the clear color to a different color and see it.  But, my geometry does not render at all.  No errors or warnings are generated.

My question is, what can you do to troubleshoot an issue like this?

Comment: If renderdoc crashes your application when trying to attach you can try hard coding some positions/colors in your shaders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RenderDoc](https://github.com/baldurk/renderdoc/wiki/Vulkan) installs with the Vulkan SDK (at least on Windows), and is a frame debugger, similar to PIX/Diagnostics, CodeXL and Nsight. It can give you a view of how the graphics pipelines are processing your data.

You should also enable the [validation layers](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/tree/master/layers) (particularly `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation`), and install a debug callback. Generally if you are triggering any 'warn' or 'error' messages, these are a good indication of why something is not executing as you'd expect.